# Delete all hidden files recursively in current directory

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, delete, hidden-files

I have a directory which contains hidden files and by that I mean, not just the files whose name starts with `.` but also the files whose name contains `~` character at the end like `somefile.txt~`.

I want to delete only those files (the remaining files need to be unaffected) in an efficient way.

How I can achieve that with a single command ?

Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr.

Comment: One way of doing this is    `rm $(ls -a | grep -e "^\.[a-zA-Z0-9_ ].*" -e ".*~")` Perhaps a bit wordy, but is does the job without deleting anything it should not.

Answer (score 3):

Not really one single command, but why make it more complicated than necessary?

```
find -type f -name ".*" -delete; rm *~
```

The first command removes all files starting with `.` and the second one all ending with `~`

Comment: Not working, got following error: `rm: cannot remove ‘.’: Is a directory
rm: cannot remove ‘..’: Is a directory`

Comment: ah yes, I overlooked this. This is because `.*` is also expanded to the directories `.` and `..`.which cannot be deleted. See my edit for an alternative command that does not cause the error.

Comment: Confirmed to work.

Comment: Still not working for me, I have hidden files with name ending in `~`, but they aren't deleted.

Comment: are they found with `ls *~`? are they write-protected?

Comment: Nope, not getting by that command either. Not even with `ls -R *~` .

Comment: what about `ls *~*`?